# OkHttp3 cannot start handshake on Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, okhttp

I make a simple request just to check if I have Internet access:

```kotlin
return try {
    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url("https://www.google.com")
        .build()

    val response = OkHttpClient()
        .newCall(request)
        .execute()

    response.body()?.close()
    response.isSuccessful
} catch (e: IOException) {
    false
}
```

And pretty often I fall into `catch` block with `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out`. I found out that OkHttp doesn't go further this line in `okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection`:

```java
private void connectTls(ConnectionSpecSelector connectionSpecSelector) throws IOException {
    // ...
    try {
        // ...
        sslSocket.startHandshake(); // never goes to the next line
        // ...
    } catch(AssertionError e) {
    // never goes here
    } finally {
    // goes here
    }
}
```

I can't figure out what happens in `sslSocket.startHandshake()` because apparently `sslSocket` is `com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket` and Android doesn't really want me to see how it works.
Is it some kind of a bug or I just do something wrong? Is there a fix or at least a workaround?

Log:

```
Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/ConscryptEngineSocket;->setUseSessionTickets(Z)V (blacklist,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)
Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/ConscryptEngineSocket;->setHostname(Ljava/lang/String;)V (blacklist,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)
Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/ConscryptEngineSocket;->setUseSessionTickets(Z)V (blacklist,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)
Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/ConscryptEngineSocket;->setHostname(Ljava/lang/String;)V (blacklist,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)
Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/ConscryptEngineSocket;->setUseSessionTickets(Z)V (blacklist,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)
Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/ConscryptEngineSocket;->setHostname(Ljava/lang/String;)V (blacklist,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)
Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/ConscryptEngineSocket;->setUseSessionTickets(Z)V (blacklist,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)
Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/ConscryptEngineSocket;->setHostname(Ljava/lang/String;)V (blacklist,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)
Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/ConscryptEngineSocket;->setUseSessionTickets(Z)V (blacklist,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)
Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/ConscryptEngineSocket;->setHostname(Ljava/lang/String;)V (blacklist,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)
```

I use Android 11 (API 30) and OkHttp3 v3.12.0.

P.S. As I remember, I can't update OkHttp to something newer because I have another dependencies that rely on OkHttp of this particular version because newer versions are backward incompatible.

Comment: It works on android 10, 9 or 8?

Comment: `buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'`, so it should be on Android 10 as well but it stopped to reproduce even on Android 11 several hours after I wrote this question. Guess, it didn't go there this time. Now I don't really have time to try to solve this problem but I may return to it later.

Comment: It doesn't work on Android 10 as well but works on Android 7.

Comment: Then check my answer and try to decrease buildtools version to android 7 if you need a quick solution

Comment: Current `compileSdkVersion` is `29`, so if I want to change `buildToolsVersion` to something older like `28.0.3`, I need to change `compileSdkVersion` to `28` too. And it is kind of problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your okhttp3 library version access any internal restricted (by new android versions) classes by reflection.

Here is described how to conform and how to find the maximal suitable solution for you: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces

or...

An quick workaround is to decrease "android build tools" version to a version where such restrictions are not implemented yet. Is a small hack to avoid restrictions on new android versions. But be careful because playmarket will not accept an application compiled with a too old "build tools", so it is not a durable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to OkHttp3 v3.12.12, this was fixed already.

See https://square.github.io/okhttp/changelog_3x/#version-3129

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't update to `3.13.0` and `3.12.12` doesn't fix this issue.

Comment: It doesn't log those reflection errors anymore, though.

Answer (score 0):

migrating to OkHttp3 4.4.0 has fixed the issue

Comment: Given you are not the OP, how can you say that this "fixed the issue"?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I was facing the same issue, I fixed the issue by doing this.

Comment: It is recommend to be explicit in this, because as it stands, it reads as if you're the OP, and that you fixed it by upgrading. While you're actually a different person, recommending the OP to fix it by upgrading (e.g. "I recommend trying to upgrade to OkHttp3 4.4.0. I had the same issue, and doing that fixed it for me", or something similar).